# In Airflow Data-aware scheduling, how could I do ""when one of the datasets in the schedule list is updated, then the DAG will be scheduled"?

Tags: airflow

**According to Airflow document:**

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.0/concepts/datasets.html#multiple-datasets

Multiple Datasets
As the schedule parameter is a list, DAGs can require multiple datasets, and the DAG will be scheduled once all datasets it consumes have been updated at least once since the last time it was run:

```
with DAG(
dag_id='multiple_datasets_example',
   schedule=[
       example_dataset_1,
       example_dataset_2,
       example_dataset_3,
   ],
   ...,
):
```

All the datasets in the schedule updated, then this consumer dag will be scheduled. This is the behavior of this dag.

What if I want "when one of the datasets in the schedule list is updated, then the DAG will be scheduled.", I could not use this approach, **I would have to use the more traditional TriggerDagRunOperator?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that as of now (Airflow 2.5.0) if you provide more than one dataset to the `schedule` parameter the DAG will wait for all of them to be updated before running. Having more configuration around this behavior is something that is being discussed, I found a reference to it on [AIP48](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-48+Data+Dependency+Management+and+Data+Driven+Scheduling) in the future work section (second to last paragraph). But yes for now you'd have to use the TriggerDagRunOperator.